# AFNetworking 2.0 Reachability not working

Tags: objective-c, ios7, reachability, afnetworking-2

I'm having some trouble making AFNetworking Reachability module to work. I have setup my AFHTTPRequestOperationManager with a ReachabilityStatusChangeBlock but it's never being called.

```
self.manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.2:3000"]];
    self.manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = self.manager.operationQueue;
    [self.manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            // we need to notify a delegete when internet conexion is lost.
            // [delegate internetConexionLost];
                NSLog(@"No Internet Conexion");
            break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                NSLog(@"WIFI");
            break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
                NSLog(@"3G");
            break;
          default:
            NSLog(@"Unkown network status");
            [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
            break;
        }
```

I have imported SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h in my .pch as the documentation says. Every time i ask for the status i get the value -1.

Any help?

**UPDATE:**

I add my PodFile here:

```
pod 'AFNetworking'              ,'~> 2.0.0'
pod 'AFNetworking/Reachability' ,'~> 2.0.0'
```

Comment: how did you import `AFNetworking`? Are you using CocoaPods?

Comment: CocoaPods. I've been working fine with AFNetworking! Is just the Reachability feature that is not working.

Comment: Can you show how you included AFNetworking in your Podfile?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I needed to start the reachability monitor.

```
[self.manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```

I find it by accident, documentation should state this in my opinion.

Comment: nice finding. Feel free to accept your own answer as soon as you can

Comment: I made a pull request in AFNetworking. Finally it was a bug. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/4bae4335c25533b5a11d7c8765b6d8a14d24974a

Comment: @bilby91 I want to resume all upload tasks when network is reconnect. Can you please explain me how is it possible?