# How to detect wifi network change in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, networking, wifi

I am working on iOS application and I would need to detect when network changes either from Wifi connection to another Wifi connection or between Wifi and 3G.

I have tried using Reachability library but it seems it does not detect changes between Wifi connections.
What can I use?

Target of the application would be App Store so I can't use private methods of Apple.

UPDATE: After some testing I have found out that when testing using simulator it works perfectly. I get notifications without any problem.
iphone problem, maybe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652465/capture-wi-fi-network-changing-event-in-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture Wi-Fi network changing event in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652465/capture-wi-fi-network-changing-event-in-ios)

Comment: I saw that already, but isn´t there another way apart from just setting timer and checking SSID. Then change will not be detected automatically

Comment: Hi @RuLoViC, Did you find the solution to this problem?. I am also facing the same issue for quite some time. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256197/1382157

Other way,

```
- (BOOL)isReachable {
return [self isReachableViaWWAN] || [self isReachableViaWiFi];
}

- (BOOL)isReachableViaWWAN {// If this return true, means it is connected to 3g
return self.networkReachabilityStatus == 
AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN;
}

- (BOOL)isReachableViaWiFi { // If this return true, means it is connected to wifi
return self.networkReachabilityStatus == 
AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi;
}
```

make sure you initialize class properly and do

```
[self.manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, making sure I am calling startMonitoring but no luck so far

Comment: Then post your code,so that everyone can see and make it out what's happening wrong.

Answer (score 0):

please see first [Reachibility](https://github.com/belkevich/reachability-ios)

After Importing class
write in .h

```
 Reachability* reachability;
```

.m class

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
 selector:@selector(handleNetworkChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil]; 
  reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]; 
 [reachability startNotifier]; 
 NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus]; 
 if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) 
 {
NSLog(@"no");
 } 
 else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFiNetwork) 
 {
NSLog(@"wifi"); 
} 
else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork) 
{
NSLog(@"cell"); 
} 
..... 

 - (void) handleNetworkChange:(NSNotification *)notice 
 {   
NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];   
if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) 
{
    NSLog(@"no");
}   
else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFiNetwork) 
{
    NSLog(@"wifi"); 
}   
else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork) 
{
    NSLog(@"cell"); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, checked that example and I have something similar implemented but it is still not working

Comment: this is working for me i dont know what problem you r facing.

Comment: I do not get notified when switching between different wifi networks