# Is it safe to use 'com.apple.system.config.network_change' notification to detect network reachability changes?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, app-store, reachability

Is it safe to use 'com.apple.system.config.network_change' notification to detect network reachability changes? Or is it considered to be a private API? For now my code looks like this:

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                nil,
                                callback,
                                "com.apple.system.config.network_change" as CFString,
                                nil,
                                .deliverImmediately);
```

And then in callback I respond to the notification.

The problem is Reachability in iOS not always detects Wi-Fi switching. For instance, if we are switching from one Wi-Fi AP to the other that system already knows (because we have used it in the past) then it happens so fast that there's no 'Disconnected' event and I cannot track the actual switching moment. Solution above works but I am sure whether my app won't be rejected for publishing in the App Store.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is considered to be a public API for now. For more details please see this thread:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/334035#334035

Answer (score 0):

I can't **exactly** answer your question, but the way I handle **Reachability** changes is using [this](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) "lib", which is pretty accurate when listening to every single change. I think you could give it a try if it fits your needs of detecting this specific moment of switching between two Wi-Fis.

If you don't want to import it - it's a **really small** file -, you can just see how it [works](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/blob/master/Sources/Reachability.swift) - basically using [`SCNetworkReachability`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachability-g7d).

Comment: I have already tried it but still under the hood it uses SCNetworkReachability and all other libraries do it too. And so in the situation that I described id doesn't recognize Wi-Fi AP change :(

Comment: Are you trying to check it in a simulator? See [this question update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45959705/8558606) - he had a problem specifically when testing with a simulator.

Comment: No, I use different devices and behavior is the same everywhere.